# java.util.NoSuchElementException while writing image on Excel file using Apache poi 3.8 in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am getting below inconsistent exception when i call resize method.
It fails 10% of time, because of below error. I can't reproduced it on my local environment.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.next(ServiceRegistry.java:836)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:528)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:513)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils.getImageDimension(ImageUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.getImageDimension(XSSFPicture.java:278)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.getPreferredSize(XSSFPicture.java:203)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.resize(XSSFPicture.java:170)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.resize(XSSFPicture.java:152)
```

Please suggest any root cause.

The code snippet which i have written as follows

```
Sheet sheet2 = workbook.createSheet("Graph");
            //feedChartToExcel = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\idnyob\\Desktop\\PcrChartImageFogX7eRH4c1551955300676.png");
            feedChartToExcel = new FileInputStream(this.imagePath);

            // Convert picture to be added into a byte array
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(feedChartToExcel);


            // Add Picture to Workbook, Specify picture type as PNG and Get an Index
            int pictureId = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
            // Close the InputStream. We are ready to attach the image to workbook now
            feedChartToExcel.close();
            // Create the drawing container
            XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing) sheet2.createDrawingPatriarch();
            //  Create an anchor point
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor();
            //  Define top left corner, and we can resize picture suitable from there
            anchor.setCol1(2);
            anchor.setRow1(1);
            // Invoke createPicture and pass the anchor point and ID
            XSSFPicture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureId);
            // Call resize method, which resizes the image
            picture.resize();
```

Comment: Why are you using [a version of Apache POI that is 7+ years old with loads of known bugs](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.8-FINAL)? What happens when you upgrade to a more modern and supported version?

Comment: Could you confirm  this exception is related to this version 3.8

Comment: According to that exception `org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils.getImageDimension` calls `javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next` without checking whether there is a next element (would be simple `Iterator.hasNext`). And after looking in the code I found that this is true even in last `apache poi 4.0.1`. But this is a violation of such basic programming rules that `apache poi` should improving that asap.

Answer (score 0):

Because the question was about the root cause of that exception, here is the answer:

[org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils.getImageDimension](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_8_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/ImageUtils.java?view=markup#l51) does the following:

If the given type is either `Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG` or `Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG` or `Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_DIB`, then it uses `javax.imageio.ImageIO` for creating a `ImageInputStream` from the given `InputStream`. Then it gets a `Iterator` of  possible `ImageReader`s for that  `ImageInputStream`. And then it does the wrong. It calls `Iterator.next` to get the first possible  `ImageReader` without checking whether the `Iterator` has a next element at all. That trows `java.util.NoSuchElementException` if there is not a next element in `Iterator`.

But why there is not a next element in `Iterator`? Since there is only one call `Iterator.next` at all, there is not even one `ImageReader` in the `Iterator`. The `Iterator` has not even one element. But that means, that `javax.imageio.ImageIO` was not able finding a currently registered `ImageReader` that claim to be able to decode the supplied `ImageInputStream`. And that means that either the given `InputStream` was not an `InputStream` from `jpeg`, `png` or `bmp` picture or there is no currently registered `ImageReader` that claim to be able to decode `jpeg`, `png` or `bmp` pictures properly.

Since it fails only inconsistent in other environments and never fails in OP's local environment, the first option is inapplicable. So my suspicion is that, if it fails, there is no currently registered `ImageReader` that claim to be able to decode `jpeg`, `png` or `bmp` pictures properly. So what I would do is:

First: Determining using what picture type it fails (`jpeg`, `png` or `bmp`).

Second: Determining in what environment it fails (operating system, `Java` version, used frameworks, ...).

The `apache poi` version is not relevant since even `apache poi 4.0.1` does the same wrong call to `Iterator.next` without checking `Iterator.hasNext` first: [org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils.getImageDimension](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/ImageUtils.java?view=markup#l62).

Comment: Image type is always same .png and os is windows, java version is 8.

Comment: Could you tell me what things i have to change.

Comment: You cannot change anything because, as said, `javax.imageio.ImageIO` was not able finding a currently registered `ImageReader` that claim to be able to decode the supplied `ImageInputStream`, which, as you told now, streams from a `png` file. And when it really only fails in other environments and never in your local environment, then there **must** be differences between the environments where it fails and your local environment. Try determining those differences to be able asking a more concrete question.

Comment: It fails in os - WIndows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (64 bit) - Service Pack 1 and java "1.8.0_40" with Failure result 10%.

Comment: Cannot test. But [Java 8 Update 40 sounds very old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8_updates). So a Java update would be worth a try in my opinion.

Comment: Is there any other way to resize the image without using XSSFPicture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureId); picture.resize(); method because problem persist inside this method?